# How do i filter an obj belong to its group using django

Tags: python, django

I have this two models Product and ProductCategory Model, how do I group the product according to their category?

**Product Data**

product = {"Apple", "Pineapple", "Pork", "Chicken", "beans", "tomato"}

**Category Data**

category = {"Fruits", "Meat", "Vegetables"}

**Expected Result**

Fruits = {"Apple", "Pineapple"}

Meat = {"Pork", "Chicken"}

Vegetables = {"beans", "tomato"}

this is my views.py

```
def Homepage(request):
    category = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(category__in=category.values_list('id'))
    return render(request, 'customAdmin/Homepage.html', {"products":products, "category":category})
```

this is my models.py

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.category}'
        return suser.format(self)

class Product(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name="Category")
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.product}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

this is the result ive got

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Apple>, <Product: Chicken>, <Product: cabbage>, <Product: ampalaya>, <Product: okra>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the code below for every category.

```py
fruits = Product.objects.filter(category=ProductCategory.objects.get(category="Fruits"))
```

Comment: can the system automatically identify which category it is in? i mean for example i add another category in my data, i dont want that every category i have to add this code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a category. For example:

```
c = ProductCategory(category='Fruits')
c.save()
```

Then create a product and link it to the category:

```
p = Product(product='Apple', category=c)
p.save()
```

Then you can do this, as in Vinayak Mikkal's answer:

```
fruits = Product.objects.filter(category=ProductCategory.objects.get(category='Fruits')
```

Comment: can the system automatically identify which category it is in? i mean for example i add another category in my data, i dont want that every category i have to add this code

Comment: How are you giving each product a category? What format is the data in?